# file not found exception while running through servlet

Tags: java, servlets, filenotfoundexception

Hi am new to java so facing some issue,i am hitting servlet from a html page where it is calling different method from different class, but while executing method of class from servlet it is throwing the file not found exception.but everything is present in correct path. while running method of class separately its working fine but from servlet it is not

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Search] in context with path [/AutomationTest] threw exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: WebContent\prop\html.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.helix.etl.automation.dao.test.read(test.java:24)
    at com.helix.etl.automation.controller.Search.doGet(Search.java:45)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

my test.java

```
public class test {
    //String filenaame="WebContent/prop/html.txt";
    /*public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        test t= new test();

        t.read(filenaame);
    }*/

    String line="";


    public List<String> read(String filename) throws IOException
    {
        File file =new File(filename);
        FileReader fi = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fi);
        List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
        while((line=in.readLine())!=null){
            tokens.add(line);
            System.out.println("entering");

        }
        return tokens;
    }
```

my servlet

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
            throws ServletException, IOException {  

response.setContentType("text/html");  
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
String Filename="WebContent/prop/html.txt";
test t = new test();

List<String> line=t.read(Filename);
for (String s : line) {
    System.out.println(s);
out.print(s);}


}
```

Comment: Hi can you share your code with the flow which you hitting from html to sevlet

Comment: Do you have the prop/html.txt file inside your application context? Your test class is reading this file and file is not there.

Comment: if am running the test class alone it running fine . but through servlet its not

Comment: Is WebContent some location within ur project or a local drive,use request.getContextPath() for location relative to project directory

Comment: within project  . But i need it to run through the method call

Comment: As a test, try setting the path to the absolute path where you have your file, just to see if you can access it at all. If you can, then your relative path is not starting off where you think it does.